# Get a more detailed return of the trackback error (error + data)

Tags: python, python-2.7, traceback

I use the following code:

```
import traceback
errors = open('ERROR(S).txt', 'a')
try:
    execfile("testing.py", {})
except Exception:
    errors.write(traceback.format_exc() + '\n')
    errors.write("\n")
errors.close()
```

For example I might receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\starter.py", line 87, in execute_subscripts
    execfile("test.py", {})
  File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
    JSONDATA = json.loads(JSONDATA)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

How can I also make it retrieve the the data inside the variable `JSONDATA` as well as this traceback?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `logging` library and log the `JSONDATA` either to stderr with a `logging.StreamHandler` or to a file with a `logging.FileHandler`.

Example:

```
l = logging.getLogger("test")
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
...
l.debug("JSON DATA: %s", JSONDATA)
...
```

I would think this is the proper way to find out what went wrong. (Alternatively you could use simple `print` or if you want to go into detail use `pdb`)

Comment: You can read more about the `logging` library here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: `logger.exception()` will also log the full traceback.

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru Unsure how to implement this into my actual code... I only want the json data to be logged if the error occurs, if not it shouldn't log it.

Comment: @Hyflex Well simply catch the exception early, when the JSONDATA is available and log it there :). If you still want to have the exception go trough call `raise` in the except block.